# how can i compound firestore datas

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to compound firestore datas. Which widget is useful for multiple data?
For instance, i have user datas and user post's datas. I want to show them in the same Card Widget, but their snapshots are different. How can i compound them ?

I write just like this, but it shows just 1 snapshot, i want to both futurebuilder and streambuilder snapshots:

note: i can't use user datas, in below it has final dataUser = snapshotUser.data;
but i can't use it, it gives an error

```
class HomePageBodyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('Posts').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot docPost) {
          return FutureBuilder(
            future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('Users')
                .doc(docPost.reference.parent.parent.id)
                .get(),
            builder: (context, snapshotUser) {
              if (!snapshotUser.hasData) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
              return homePageCard(context, dataPost: docPost, dataUser: snapshotUser.data);
            },
          );
        }).toList());
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it, like this:

```
class HomePageBodyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('Posts').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final dataPost = snapshot.data.docs[index];
              return FutureBuilder(
                future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('Users')
                    .doc(dataPost.reference.parent.parent.id)
                    .get(),
                builder: (context, snapshotUser) {
                  final dataUser = snapshotUser.data;
                  if (!snapshotUser.hasData) {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                  return homePageCard(context,
                      dataPost: dataPost, dataUser: dataUser);
                },
              );
            });
      });
}
```